# Slow PostgreSQL 9.3 query

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, postgresql-9.3

Greeting all,

I have a query that looks like:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT empRec.lastName, empRec.FirstName 
FROM schedXEmp 
INNER JOIN empRec ON 
    empRec.selfManagerId = 1 and empRec.employeeNumber = schedXEmp.employeeNumber 
WHERE schedXEmp.schedId = 22480 AND deactivatedTS > NOW () 
ORDER BY empRec.lastName, empRec.FirstName;
```

I am getting:

```
Sort  (cost=633.26..633.27 rows=1 width=136) (actual time=570.691..570.692 rows=1 loops=1)"
Sort Key: emprec.lastname, emprec.firstname"
Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB"
->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..633.25 rows=1 width=136) (actual time=532.276..570.664 rows=1 loops=1)"
    Join Filter: (schedxemp.employeenumber = emprec.employeenumber)"
      Rows Removed by Join Filter: 106"
      ->  Seq Scan on emprec  (cost=0.00..4.34 rows=1 width=144) (actual time=0.012..0.207 rows=107 loops=1)"
            Filter: (selfmanagerid = 1)"
      ->  Seq Scan on schedxemp  (cost=0.00..628.43 rows=39 width=8) (actual time=5.124..5.323 rows=1 loops=107)"
            Filter: ((schedid = 22480) AND (deactivatedts > now()))"
            Rows Removed by Filter: 23405"
Total runtime: 570.753 ms"
```

Although this lag might not seem important, it does cause an issue as the query is called about 250 in a single page, causing timeout.

Within the join, if I remove the **empRec.selfManagerId = 1 and** portion, then everything execute in less than 30ms, much better.

In my DDL I do have an index defined as:

```
CREATE INDEX emprec_sm_enum_ndx ON employeekeeper.emprec
  USING btree (selfmanagerid, employeenumber);
```

## My data

empRec has very little data, 110 records.
For now all values in empRec.selfManagerId = 1 (so not needed for now), things will change as pple join the application.

schedxemp is for a many-to-many relation. It holds a bit less than 25K records.

At this point I can't really think what I can try to isolate/solve the problem.

Comment: "*the query is called about 250 in a single page*" - that sounds like a bad design to begin with. Why not run it once with all parameters so that it returns 250 rows?

Comment: Agree, Considerable refactoring. Is in the plans for a rainy day. It is -10c here now. No rain in sight. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This index should help:

```
CREATE INDEX ON schedxemp (schedid, deactivatedts);
```

Comment: Well, that did it. I was sure the bottle nexk was in empRec. Thanks a bunch.